# Comparison of variances between multiple time-series

Tags: sequences-and-series, regression

I am trying to perform a comparison of variances of multiple time-series (weekly average prices).  I have found a multiple linear regression model for each respective series with a lag model.  Is it correct for me to calculate variances based on the residuals between actual data and my calculated models or am I way off here?  Could use some suggestions.